# problemas checksum

Tags: c

Estoy tratando generar el checksum de un paquete icmpv6 de forma de ejemplo. Esta es la función que estoy usando:

```html
uint16_t checksum (uint16_t *addr, int len)
{
  int count = len;
  register uint32_t sum = 0;
  uint16_t answer = 0;

  // Sum up 2-byte values until none or only one byte left.
  while (count > 1) {
    sum += *(addr++);
    count -= 2;
  }

  // Add left-over byte, if any.
  if (count > 0) {
    sum += *(uint8_t *) addr;
  }

  // Fold 32-bit sum into 16 bits; we lose information by doing this,
  // increasing the chances of a collision.
  // sum = (lower 16 bits) + (upper 16 bits shifted right 16 bits)
  while (sum >> 16) {
    sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);
  }

  // Checksum is one's compliment of sum.
  answer = ~sum;

  return (answer);
}
```

y esta es la variable que le estoy insertando:

```html
nread = read(tun_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
for(i = 8; i < 40 ; i++)
{
    buf[i-8] = buffer[i];  
    j++;
}
buf[j] = 0; j++;

buf[j] = 0; j++;

aux2 |= buffer[4] << 8;

aux2 |= buffer[5] << 0; 

buf[j] = aux2 / 256;j++;
buf[j] = aux2 % 256;j++;

buf[j] = 0;j++;
buf[j] = 0;j++;
buf[j] = 0;j++;
buf[j] = 58;j++;
buf[j] = buffer[40];j++;
buf[j] = buffer[41];j++;
buf[j] = buffer[44];j++;
buf[j] = buffer[45];j++;
buf[j] = buffer[46];j++;
buf[j] = buffer[47];j++;
buf[j] = 0;j++;
buf[j] = 0;j++;
for(i = 48; i < nread ; i++)
{
    buf[j] = buffer[i];
    j++  ;
}


printf("%i\n", checksum((uint16_t *)buf,j));
```

Los valores obtenidos son:

valor que debiese ser checksum 65522 y el
valor que obtengo 57975

Estoy atento a alguna ayuda

Comment: ¿Cual es el rango de `uint16_t`? ¿Podría ser que tengas un valor que desborda el rango del tipo?

Comment: ¿De dónde estás sacando ese 65522? Si lo estás sacando de un tcpdump, o similar, ¿puedes comprobar si es correcto (`-v` en `tcpdump`)? Un "problema" típico es que sea la tarjeta de red quien calcule el checksum de los paquetes enviados desde una máquina.

Comment: Estoy utilizando una interfaz  tun0.

Comment: Este es el buffer original :                                                                           60-0-0-0-0-12-3a-40-ffffffbb-ffffffbb-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-1-ffffffbb-ffffffbb-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-2-ffffff80-0-ffffffe5-ffffffb0-d-ffffffb5-0-ffffffba-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9.

Comment: Este es el buffer que se envía a la función checksum: ffffffbb-ffffffbb-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-1-ffffffbb-ffffffbb-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-2-0-0-0-12-0-0-0-3a-ffffff80-0-d-ffffffb5-0-ffffffba-0-0-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9

Comment: Tu función es **exacta** (RFC 1071). El fallo está en como la aplicas. No puedo ser mas concreto, pero asegurate de aplicar el checksum a los campos correctos de los paquetes (solo a partir de las direcciones en la cabecera IP, no a los demás), consulta https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2463#section-2.3 (mi ingles no da para tanto); creo que hay que modificar un valor **antes** del calculo.

Answer (score 1):

A ver. En esta parte de tu código

```
  // Sum up 2-byte values until none or only one byte left.
  while (count > 1) {
    sum += *(addr++);
    count -= 2;
  }

  // Add left-over byte, if any.
  if (count > 0) {
    sum += *(uint8_t *) addr;
  }
```

Recorres el buffer pasado y vas sumando el valor de sus bytes, tomandolos como **16 bits**, y, si sobra algun byte (el tamaño del buffer es impar), lo sumas **como 8 bits**.

Ese punto te puede dar problemas, dependiendo del *ENDIAN* de la arquitectura en el que lo ejecutes.

Prueba a cambiarlo por un `uint16_t`, a ver que pasa.

```
// Add left-over byte, if any.
if (count > 0) {
  sum += *(uint16_t *) addr;
}
```

**EDITO**

Si lo haces como digo, creo que deberías de añadir a mano un **\0** al final de `addr`, para que no tome valores indeseados.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero no pudo resolver mi problema. Este es el buffer original 60-0-0-0-0-12-3a-40-ffffffbb-ffffffbb-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-1-ffffffbb-ffffffbb-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-2-ffffff80-0-ffffffe5-ffffffb0-d-ffffffb5-0-ffffffba-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9

Comment: el buffer que mando a la función checksum es el siguiente ffffffbb-ffffffbb-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-1-ffffffbb-ffffffbb-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-2-0-0-0-12-0-0-0-3a-ffffff80-0-d-ffffffb5-0-ffffffba-0-0-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9

Comment: @Trauma, muy buena observación, para que le quede un poco más claro a Tomas: el orden en el que quedan empaquetados los bytes en un `uint16_t` es dependiente de la arquitectura, por ejemplo: si el contenido de `addr` (2 bytes) fuera `0xDEAD`, al dereferenciar un puntero via cast con un tipo `uint8_t` (1 byte) podrías estar accediendo al primer byte `0xDE` en arquitecturas big endian o al segundo `0xAD` en little endian. Conclusión: No escribas código dependiente del procesador.

Comment: Gracias @KeineLust; estoy documentándome sobre la pregunta, para responder *a full*. Me gusta el tema xD

Comment: Si os sirve de ayuda, la forma correcta (cross-plattform) de extraer bytes es usando operadores de desplazamiento de bits (shift operators): `<<` y `>>`, [este hilo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730321/standard-cross-platform-way-for-bit-manipulation/12730780#12730780) lo explica muy bien: `The definition of shifts is mathematical for unsigned types or positive values in signed types (*), and therefore not affected by the underlying hardware representation.`